# How to make each row of android listview a trapezium instead of ractangle?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-custom-view

[image]

I want to customize my listview to achieve this design,are there any library available for this?what can be best way to achieve this.Are there any disadvantage with such designs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two different ways

- add an image instead of divider containing these tilt lines you can do this by using a simple line of code in your layout or in your class

  ```
  android:divider="@drawable/divider_image"
  ```

  or you can change it in you java class like this

  ```
  list.setDivider(R.drawable.divider_image);
  ```
- the second way of achieving this is you set a static image in you item layout below the item and change it according to your need as if the item is odd set a different image and if the item is even set a different image

  ```
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageViewDivider"
      android:src="@drawable/divider_image"
      android:scaleType="fitXY" />
  ```

  and change the image in java class

  ```
     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDivider);
     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.divider_image);
  ```